# Global Headers for all Controllers (nestJs swagger)

Tags: swagger, nestjs

Is there a way to globally add required headers to all endpoints / controllers in NestJS?

There is a controller bound decorator `@ApiHeader`. Is there a way to apply this to all endpoints?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Shortest way I have found is to do the following:

```js
export function Headers() {
  return applyDecorators(
    ApiHeader({
      name: 'header1',
      description: "description"
    }),
    ApiHeader({
      name: 'header2',
      description: "description"
    }),
    ApiHeader({
      name: 'header3',
      description: "description"
    })
  );
}
```

```js
@Headers()
@Controller('some-controller')
export class ContactsController {}
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! Since your answer is nearly 3 years old, perhaps you found even shorter way?

Comment: I haven't been using NestJs as I switched jobs, so unfortunately no.

Comment: can we set it as global into nestJs

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DocumentBuilder.addGlobalParameters` method.

Unfortunately, it's not described in the documentation, but here is my example:

```js
SwaggerModule.setup(
    'docs',
    application, // your NestJS application created by NestFactory.create
    SwaggerModule.createDocument(
      application,
      new DocumentBuilder()
        .setTitle('My application')
        .addGlobalParameters({
          in: 'header',
          required: false,
          name: 'x-global-header',
          schema: {
            example: 'some value',
          },
        })
        .build(),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it's a way better approach than the current accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, you can add global headers in main.ts

```
const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Kuber apis')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addBearerAuth(
      { type: 'http', scheme: 'bearer', bearerFormat: 'JWT', in: 'header' },
      'JWT',
    )
    .addGlobalParameters({
      name: 'assetId',
      in: 'header',
    })
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);
```

It shows up in every route[image]